# Is Officer K ever betrayed?

Tags: plot-explanation, blade-runner-2049

I was reading articles about the movie and they claim that K was drawn into the world of deception and betrayal. I've watched Blade Runner 2049 several times now, but I'm struggling to find any scenes where K is betrayed.

Am I missing something entirely or does K not get betrayed in the movie?

Quotes from articles:
From https://www.13thfloor.co.nz/blade-runner-2049-movie-review/

> Ryan Gosling is ‘K,’ a blade runner returning from what appeared to be an ordinary mission to destroy a replicant who ... finds himself drawn into a mind-numbing spiral of deception and betrayal and just what does it even mean to be human?

From Blade Runner and the archiving of memory and identity https://ro.uow.edu.au/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1734&context=asdpapers

> K spots two sets of similarly carved small wooden animals displayed alongside Rachael's photograph in amongst the eclectic surroundings of Deckard's frozen in time Las Vegas hotel residence. The image of the wooden horse - a Trojan horse perhaps, carrying the memory that will ultimately turn out to betray him by belonging to another? - also echoes back to the imagery of the small unicorn origami figure of the first film

Answer (score 10):

Based on what I can read in your first version of the question, it is not that K was deceived and betrayed, but the whole world of Blade Runner 2049 is described as full of deception and betrayal. So other people betray each other very often on a daily basis, and that's just it.

After updating the question, the answer to the first quote is that the spiral of deception and betrayal - Luv betraying the police lieutenant Joshi, Wallace betraying Deckard with fake Rachael, and so on, and so on, remember what Doctor House said - everybody lies!

The second quote refers to the fact, that he had memories of someone else implanted inside his mind. He was tricked to believe he was someone else and when he found out it was all a lie, it is like he was betrayed by his maker and everyone he knows. Also, the quote states - he was betrayed by his memories.

On the topic of more direct betrayals - somehow K was tracked to the place where he met Deckard. This is where he might have been betrayed, either by Joi, who was a tracker or by others revealing how to track him down.